# How to post json values with multiple parameters in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, asmx, ios10

`let parameters2Send = Key:(value as 3 key-value pairs)`
Eg: paramtoSend = Key:(param1,param2,utcdate)

The response is like {"key" : "fail/success"}
I have been trying many ways but not successful. Could you please help us.

Answer (score 0):

For request parameters

let parameters2Send = ["key1" : "value", "key2" : "value" , "key3" : "value" ]